# return value of a function when assigned to variable,adding extra (),in python

Tags: python

I just wrote a simple method in python

```
def function1(arg):
  print "value is=",arg
  return ("value is=",arg)

res=function1(5)
print res
```

The O/P is

```
value is= 5
('value is=', 5)
```

Why it is adding `('')`,when returned and how to eliminate this?
My expectation is ,it should return the same value as it has printed inside the function i.e ,my O/P should be

```
value is= 5
value is= 5
```

Comment: can be formated

Comment: Just return your string instead of returning your string _and_ your argument.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define a single string and format it with the desired value:

```
def function1(arg):
  print "value is=",arg
  return "value is= {}".format(arg)

res=function1(5)
print res
```